# My acer tree is dying and doesn't have any leaves

Tags: leaves, maple

My acer has no leaves left.

[image]

What can I do?

Comment: Please provide with the information such as watering routine, sunlight, weather etc...

Comment: Most likely it's dead. Maybe not, but most likely. [Edit] to provide details (where in the world, how old, what size pot, and what's already requested above,) but don't expect miracles.

Comment: What kind of acer?

Comment: Im in the uk Midlands- in terms of watering it’s mostly rain - sun its in sort of a bright spot bt not too much heat it did have keaves now theyv all gone can i revive? The pot has a circumference of about 49cm im not sure how old it is was bought a year ago, also i have no idea wat type of acer it is i think maple, it used to have red purple leaves

Comment: So presumably a Japanese Red Maple, as the "usual" small red-leafed maple in garden-center commerce.

Comment: Yes that sound right - newbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carefully scratch the bark with a coin or thumbnail. If it shows green, the tree is alive. Practice on a shrub so you know what you're looking for. More detail [here](https://www.starkbros.com/growing-guide/article/how-to-do-a-scratch-test), for example.

Comment: Thank u so much i will try this

Comment: @Khan -  You're welcome.